# How to install a modified python package

Tags: python, django, pip, django-import-export

I have modified the django-import-export package, now I need to upload my application to Heroku and use the modifications that I have made. I have created a github repository and uploaded the files of the folder import_export. Now How can I use this modificated package into my project?

Comment: In your `requirements.txt` point to the Github URL; use [VCS format](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support).

Comment: And how can I point that into my requirementes.txt? Just use git+https://github.com/MatheusCE/import-export-customized.git#egg=import-export-customized?

Comment: Yes, that's the way.